# duvida sobre autenticação php

Tags: php, html, mysql

Quando faço o teste de *login*, vou para `autenticar.php`, porém a tela fica em branco em vez de direcionar para a pagina principal.

comando msql e php testado e funcionando)

```
<script language="javascript">
    function sucesso(){
        setTimeout("window.location='principal.html'", 4000);
    }
    function failed(){
        setTimeout("window.location='login.html'", 4000);
    }
</script>
```

```
    $consulta = mysqli_query("SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE usuario = '$email' AND senha = '$pass'") or die (mysqli_error($conexao));
    $linhas = mysqli_num_rows($consulta);

    if($linhas == 0){
        echo"O login falhou. Você será redirecionado para a página de login em 4 segundos.";
        echo"<script language='javascript'>failed()</script>";
    } else {
        $_SESSION["email"]=$_POST["email"];
        $_SESSION["senha"]=$_POST["pass"];
        echo"Você foi logado com sucesso. Redirecionando em 4 segundos.";
        echo"<script language='javascript'>sucesso()</script";
    }
?>
```

Comment: Acredito que você tenha capacidade de elaborar um título melhor que esse ([Como escolher um bom título?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4394/5878)) Se pressionar `Ctrl+U` na página em branco, o que aparece?

Comment: Se alguma resposta resolveu seu problema marque-a como aceita. Veja como em https://i.stack.imgur.com/evLUR.png e veja porque em https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1078/como-e-por-que-aceitar-uma-resposta/1079#1079

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Acerta a sua declaração com a string da conexão

**exemplo**

**$con** `= new mysqli ("localhost", "USUARIO", "SENHA", "NOME_DB");`

$consulta = mysqli_query(**$con**,"SELECT......

```
$consulta = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE usuario = '$email' AND senha = '$pass'") or die (mysqli_error($conexao));
```

> Outro detalhe a tag de fechamento do script `</script` falta um `>`

```
echo"<script language='javascript'>sucesso()</script";
```

corrija para

```
echo"<script language='javascript'>sucesso()</script>";
```

Answer (score 0):

Ao final do script php, caso o Login esteja ok, adiciona a linha:

```
header('location: login_ok.php');
```

Onde "login_ok.php" seria o nome da página a ser redirecionada.

Comment: Além disso que o Rodrigo disse, você não vai precisar do redirecionamento via JavaScript como você fez.

Comment: Qual a relação entre redirecionar com JS ou com o `Location` e o problema apresentado na pergunta?

Comment: Não precisa redirecionar com o JS. Uma vez estando dentro do PHP (servidor), ele mesmo pode redirecionar o usuário ao invés de devolver para o browser redirecionar pelo JS.

Comment: Sim, mas não entendi porque isso resolve o problema - para falar a verdade, não entendi nem qual é o problema.

Comment: Isso resolve. O Eduardo disse que depois do login a tela fica branca e não vai a lugar nenhum. Colocando o comando que eu mencionei no php, ao efetuar o login o usuário pode ser redirecionado "para dentro" do sistema.